# Magento layout block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

i changed the images directly in the coding of the home page in the panel and now its showing on the home page only before doing this it was showing on every product page any help will be appreciated.

HOME PAGE - SCREENSHOT
[image]

PRODUCT PAGE - SCREENSHOT
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you used porto theme right?
to change image in product detail right sidebar
porto gives you static block you can change image directly from that
just goto static blocks-> and search "right" after that you can see some block open related block look like "product right" keyword and change image